# How does YouTube get its player embedded as iframe in the Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, iframe, youtube, embed

I'm wondering how to embed some HTML code in a facebook post on the wall..
I've already searched for that and came to the conclusion that ATM it's not possible (Am i right???)

But inspecting the code of the facebook news feed page i have noticed that a YouTube video was coded as an **iframe**!
What happened there?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, HTML cannot be posted to the Facebook wall. The reason Youtube videos show up is actually a by product of the Facebook coding. When a user posts a URL to a Youtube video the Facebook wall automatically converts it to a video in an iFrame.

Comment: as i thought, facebook is offering a 'special treatment' in regards to youtube... Thank you